# Pandas to sql while keeping decimal

Tags: python, sql, pandas

So I'm having pandas fetch a table containing name, date, price among other things from a website. This is done without hiccups. Problem is, I'd like to parse this data into a sqlite database. Everything runs smoothly except for the price, which has it's decimals removed.

Prices are written in this style on the webpage and in the dataframe:

- 9,20
- 149,935
- 23,431

and gets converted into this:

- 920
- 149935
- 23431

the [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) does not contain any references to anything in the ballpark of this, as far as I understand it at least.

Code if anyone is interested:

```
    def fetcher(self):
    r = requests.get("https://")
    df_list = pd.read_html(r.text) # this parses all the tables in webpages to a list
    df_list[0].pop("Status") #removes column status
    df_list[0].pop("Unnamed: 15") #removes column "unnamed: 15", this is a horrible solution... but it works
    df_list[0].to_sql('mine321', conn)
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of your price column to "float", looks like it is set up as "int".

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to stem from when the DataFrame was converted into a list.

Changing out

> df_list = pd.read_html(r.text)

into the following

> df_list = pd.read_html(r.text, decimal=',', thousands='.')

Seems to have solved it. Though I will not vouch for this being a particularly good solution, might end up messing something else up. Works for my problem though.